# Find max value for each year in file. How to take leap years into account?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, max, leap-year

I have a set of 55 years worth of data in one 3D array (.nc file). Data was taken every 3 hrs over the 55 years. The shape of the array is `(163520,64,128)`

I need to find the maximum value for each year at each coordinate (64,128), so I can then eventually plot it on a global map.  I'm trying to find a simple way of looping through it so I can get the max for each year and the results end up into an array with shape `(55,64,128)`

I'm just not sure how to do that considering there are leap years. Is there a simple way to add years to the data in a way that would allow me to loop it by year? I'm just really unsure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a job for pandas with a `DatetimeIndex`... do you know the start and end times?

Comment: *Or* [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html), give the shape of your data.